# sunGrid cluster: qsub error "Unable to run job: hostnames may not be empty string"

Tags: sungridengine, qsub

I'm submitting jobs to sunGrid cluster, and I want my log file to have it's start time as its name. For that I used the next command:

```
qsub -j y -o job_`date "+%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M"`.log job.sh
```

But I got the next error message:

```
Unable to read script file because of error: ERROR! invalid option argument "-f"
```

I didn't find a "-f" in my script, so I tried to replace the date execution to the current date:

```
qsub -j y -o job_2014_10_23_16:36.log job.sh
```

But, then I got the next error:

```
Unable to run job: hostnames may not be empty string.
```

What can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found that the error was using a colon in the output file name, so it was looking for a hostname:option argument.
Replacing the colon with another character (e.g. underscore) fixed it:

```
qsub -j y -o job_2014_10_23_16_36.log job.sh
```

Great!

Comment: Same here, there was a colon in the output log path. Removing the colon fixed the problem